# Why does my function only work as function(), and not function(param1, param2 etc.)?

Tags: javascript

I am building Rock, Paper, Scissors in Javascript following along The Odin Project syllabus.

When creating a function to execute a single round of the game I used two parameters (playerSelection, compSelection), variables I thought were relevant to the function.

Instead, when executing with these parameters, the game would default to a tie message located on the last else if statement of the conditional block.

I used console.log to verify the equality of the two parameters as the condition for the tie message to occur would be (playerSelection === compSelection). It would recognise when the game was actually a tie or not as it output 'true' and 'false' when expected whilst verifying the equality.

It worked when I removed the two parameters and ran it as singleround() rather than singleround(playerSelection, compSelection).

I'm struggling to understand why, and cannot seem to understand the functionality of parameters.

Can anyone summarise my problem?

```js
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
let playerSelection = prompt("Please choose Rock, Paper or Scissors!").toLowerCase();
let compSelection;

(function getComputerChoice() {

  if (randomNumber === 1) {
    return compSelection = "rock";
  } else if (randomNumber === 2) {
    return compSelection = "paper";
  } else if (randomNumber === 3) {
    return compSelection = "scissors";
  }
})();

console.log(randomNumber);
console.log(compSelection);
console.log(playerSelection);

(function singleround(playerSelection, compSelection) {

  if (playerSelection === "rock" && compSelection === "paper") {
    console.log("Oh No! You lost, Paper beats Rock :(");
  } else if (playerSelection === "rock" && compSelection === "scissors") {
    console.log("Well done! You won, Rock beats Scissors!");
  } else if (playerSelection === "paper" && compSelection === "rock") {
    console.log("Well done! You won, Paper beats Rock!");
  } else if (playerSelection === "paper" && compSelection === "scissors") {
    console.log("Oh No! You lost, Scissors beats Paper :(");
  } else if (playerSelection === "scissors" && compSelection === "rock") {
    console.log("Oh No! You lost, Rock beats Scissors :(");
  } else if (playerSelection === "scissors" && compSelection === "paper") {
    console.log("Well done! You won, Scissors beats Paper!");
  } else if (playerSelection === compSelection) {
    console.log("It's a tie! Try again.");
  } else {
    console.log("Uh Oh! Something's gone wrong. Refresh the page to try again!");
  }
})();

console.log(playerSelection === compSelection);
```

Comment: You're not actually passing the parameters to the function

Comment: The problem is because, for some reason, you've defined your functions with arguments inside [IIFEs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) without arguments...? Not sure why you've done that. Remove the IIFEs and invoke the functions directly onload, if required.

Comment: I will remove the self-invoking function, I used these because I was unsure on what parameters to use or whether I even needed to use them when calling the function.

Comment: On a side note: IFFEs in modern JS don't really add much these days, if using `let / const`, you can create block scopes avoiding globals without the funky syntax.  eg.  `{ const getComputerChoice = () => {...};  getComputerChoice(); }`    IOW: You can create totally none global scope by just using   `{}`     ->  `{ ....lots of code that is not global }`..

Answer (score 2):

Your combinations of IIFEs and returning compSelection=something is not helping

If you pass the choices to the IIFE it will work (see [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77523626/295783))

Here is a simpler and IMNHO more elegant version using a dictionary. The lookup gives the winner. The lookup table is generated once.

```js
const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
const winConditions = {
  "rock": "scissors",
  "paper": "rock",
  "scissors": "paper"
};

function singleround(playerSelection, compSelection) {
  if (playerSelection === compSelection) {
    return "It's a tie! Try again.";
  } else if (winConditions[playerSelection] === compSelection) {
    return `Well done! You won, ${playerSelection.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + playerSelection.slice(1)} beats ${compSelection.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + compSelection.slice(1)}!`;
  } else {
    return `Oh No! You lost, ${compSelection.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + compSelection.slice(1)} beats ${playerSelection.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + playerSelection.slice(1)} :(`;
  }
}

let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
let playerSelection = prompt("Please choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors!").toLowerCase();
let compSelection = choices[randomNumber];

console.log("Player selected:", playerSelection);
console.log("Computer selected:", compSelection);

console.log(singleround(playerSelection, compSelection));
```

If you want the 5 choice version it is little more tricky.
I have also added a few extras to this version, like error checking and DRYness (Don't Repeat Yourself)

```js
const winConditions = {
  "rock": ["scissors", "lizard"],
  "paper": ["rock", "spock"],
  "scissors": ["paper", "lizard"],
  "lizard": ["paper", "spock"],
  "spock": ["scissors", "rock"]
};
const choices = Object.keys(winConditions);

const capitalizeFirstLetter = (string) => string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
const singleround = (playerSelection, compSelection) => {
  if (playerSelection === compSelection) return "It's a tie! Try again.";
  // lookup to see the computer selection is in the list of losing conditions
  if (winConditions[playerSelection].includes(compSelection))
    return `Well done! You won, ${capitalizeFirstLetter(playerSelection)} beats ${capitalizeFirstLetter(compSelection)}!`;
  return `Oh No! You lost, ${capitalizeFirstLetter(compSelection)} beats ${capitalizeFirstLetter(playerSelection)} :(`;
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => { // when page has loaded
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
  let playerSelection = prompt(`Please choose among ${choices.join(', ')}`)?.toLowerCase(); // ?. is optional chaining in case cancel is pressed
  let compSelection = choices[randomNumber];
  if (playerSelection && choices.includes(playerSelection)) {
    console.log("Player selected:", capitalizeFirstLetter(playerSelection));
    console.log("Computer selected:", capitalizeFirstLetter(compSelection));
    console.log(singleround(playerSelection, compSelection));
  }
  console.log("Thanks for playing");
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Rock crushes Scissors and crushes Lizard.</li>
  <li>Paper covers Rock and disproves Spock.</li>
  <li>Scissors cuts Paper and decapitates Lizard.</li>
  <li>Lizard eats Paper and poisons Spock.</li>
  <li>Spock smashes Scissors and vaporizes Rock.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

because you are using an [IIFE function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) ( function immediately invoked )

the exact code is this

```js
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
let playerSelection = prompt("Please choose Rock, Paper or Scissors!").toLowerCase();
let compSelection;

(function getComputerChoice() {

  if (randomNumber === 1) {
    return compSelection = "rock";
  } else if (randomNumber === 2) {
    return compSelection = "paper";
  } else if (randomNumber === 3) {
    return compSelection = "scissors";
  }
})();

console.log(randomNumber);
console.log(compSelection);
console.log(playerSelection);

(function singleround(playerSelection, compSelection) {

  if (playerSelection === "rock" && compSelection === "paper") {
    console.log("Oh No! You lost, Paper beats Rock :(");
  } else if (playerSelection === "rock" && compSelection === "scissors") {
    console.log("Well done! You won, Rock beats Scissors!");
  } else if (playerSelection === "paper" && compSelection === "rock") {
    console.log("Well done! You won, Paper beats Rock!");
  } else if (playerSelection === "paper" && compSelection === "scissors") {
    console.log("Oh No! You lost, Scissors beats Paper :(");
  } else if (playerSelection === "scissors" && compSelection === "rock") {
    console.log("Oh No! You lost, Rock beats Scissors :(");
  } else if (playerSelection === "scissors" && compSelection === "paper") {
    console.log("Well done! You won, Scissors beats Paper!");
  } else if (playerSelection === compSelection) {
    console.log("It's a tie! Try again.");
  } else {
    console.log("Uh Oh! Something's gone wrong. Refresh the page to try again!");
  }
})(playerSelection, compSelection);

console.log(playerSelection === compSelection);
```

you need to specify the parameters you will pass to the **singleroun**d function in round brackets at the end.

For example this iife function

```
(function(a, b)) {

     var c = a + " " + b;
     console.log(c);

}("Hello", "World"));
```

returns "Hello World" in to console.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated by others, the use of an IIFE is unnecessary, moreover there are some code smells that stink up the whole thing such as:

```
let compSelection;

function getComputerChoice() {
  if (randomNumber === 1) {
    return compSelection = "rock";
  } else if (randomNumber === 2) {
    return compSelection = "paper";
  } else if (randomNumber === 3) {
    return compSelection = "scissors";
  }
}
```

The code above should either pass `randomNumber` and return "rock", "paper", or "scissors", or just assign "rock", "paper", or "scissors" to `compSelection`.

```
function getComputerChoice(randomNumber) {
  if (randomNumber === 1) {
    compSelection = "rock";
  } else if (randomNumber === 2) {
    compSelection = "paper";
  } else if (randomNumber === 3) {
    compSelection = "scissors";
  } 
  return compSelection;
}
```

In cases where user interaction is involved, like in a game, you will have specific data from the user and a few predetermined results.

| User Data | Results |
| --- | --- |
| rock | win, lose, or tie |
| paper | win, lose, or tie |
| scissors | win, lose, or tie |

So the only parameter you really need is what the user gives you. The following code is a function:

1. that takes a number 0, 1, or 2 ("rock", "paper", or "scissors")
2. then generates a random number in the range of 0 to 2 ("rock", "paper", or "scissors")
3. and then compares the user number vs. the random number.
4. it returns a text announcing if the user lost, won, or tied.

   ```
   msg[0] = `You win! Rock beats Scissors.`;
   msg[1] = `It's a draw! Paper vs. Paper.`;
   msg[2] = `You lose! Scissors beats Paper.`;
   ```

### Example A

Simple interface - basic game function

```js
// Pass 0, 1, or 2
const play = picked => {
  // Generates 0, 1, ot 2
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  
  const rps = ["Rock ", "Paper ", "Scissors ✂️"];
  const msg = [
    `You win! ${rps[picked]} beats ${rps[random]}.`,
    `It's a draw! ${rps[picked]} vs. ${rps[random]}.`,
    `You lose! ${rps[random]} beats ${rps[picked]}.`
  ];
  /**
   * This is a chained ternary operator which is a terse
   * version of flow control (if, else if, else).
   * DETAILS:
   * if (CONDITION) ? {STATEMENT} : 
   * else if (CONDITION) ? {STATEMENT} :
   * else {STATEMENT} 
   *
   * if 'picked' equals 'random' + 1 OR 'picked' is 0 
   * AND 'random' is 2, [?]
   * then return the first text of array msg. (msg[0] WIN)
   * 
   * [:] else if 'picked' equals 'random', [?]
   * then return the second text of array msg. (msg[1] TIE)
   *
   * [:] else return the third text of array msg. (msg[2] LOSS)
   */
  return picked == random + 1 || (picked == 0 && random == 2) ? msg[0] :
    picked == random ? msg[1] :
    msg[2];
};

const form = document.forms.roshambo;
const fc = form.elements;

const userChoice = e => {
  if (e.target.name === "pick") {
    const radio = fc.pick;
    let pick = Number(radio.value);
    let outcome = play(pick);
  
    fc.results.value = outcome;
  }
}
  
form.onchange = userChoice;
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<form id="roshambo">
  <label>
  Rock <input name="pick" type="radio" value="0">
</label>
  <label>
  Paper <input name="pick" type="radio" value="1">
</label>
  <label>
  Scissors <input name="pick" type="radio" value="2">
</label><br>
  <output id="results"></output>
</form>
```

## Example B

Complex interface - keeps track of wins, ties, and losses

```js
const RPS = document.forms.RPS;
const fc = RPS.elements;
const picks = Array.from(fc.choice);
const scores = Array.from(fc.score);
const modal = document.querySelector("dialog");
let points = [0, 0, 0];

const play = picked => { 

  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  
  const rps = ["Rock ", "Paper ", "Scissors ✂️"];
  const msg = [
    `You win! ${rps[picked]} beats ${rps[random]}.`, 
    `It's a draw! ${rps[picked]} vs. ${rps[random]}.`, 
    `You lose! ${rps[random]} beats ${rps[picked]}.`
  ];
  
  let result = 
    picked == random + 1 || (picked == 0 && random == 2) ? msg[0] :
    picked == random ? msg[1] : 
    msg[2];
    
  return [result, msg.indexOf(result)];
};

const clear = e => {

  e.preventDefault();
  
  picks.forEach((pck, idx, arr) => arr[idx].classList.remove("active"));
  points.forEach((pts, idx, arr) => arr[idx] = 0);
  scores.forEach((scr, idx, arr) => arr[idx].value = "0");
  
  fc.outcome.value = "";
  if (e.type == "submit") {
    RPS.submit();
  }
};
    
const roshambo = e => {  

  if (e.target.matches("button")) {
    let pick = Number(e.target.value);  
    let result = play(pick);
        
    picks.forEach((pck, idx, arr) => arr[idx].classList.remove("active"));
    e.target.classList.add("active");
    
    fc.outcome.value = result[0];
    points[result[1]] = points[result[1]] + 1;
    scores[result[1]].textContent = "";
    scores[result[1]].value = points[result[1]];
  }
};  

fc.start.onclick = e => modal.showModal();

RPS.onclick = roshambo;
RPS.onsubmit = clear;
RPS.onreset = clear;
```

```css
:root {
  font: 5vmin/1.15 "Segoe UI"
}

fieldset {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 1.3rem;
}

legend {
  margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 700
}

button {
  padding: 0.25rem 0.75rem;
}

button + button {
  margin-left: 0.25rem;
}

button,
input {
  width: 8rem;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label {
  width: 6rem;
  text-align: center;
}

label,
output {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

label output {
  font-family: Consolas;
  min-height: 100%;
}

[type="submit"],
[type="reset"] {
  float: right;
  margin: 0.5rem 0.25rem 0 0
}

#start {
  margin: 15vh calc(50% - 4rem) 0;
}

.active {
  background: black;
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<button id="start" type="button" form="RPS">Start</button>

<dialog>
  <form id="RPS" method="dialog">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Rock, Paper, Scissors</legend>
      <button name="choice" type="button" value="0">Rock </button>
      <button name="choice" type="button" value="1">Paper </button>
      <button name="choice" type="button" value="2">Scissors ✂️</button>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <output id="outcome"></output>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <label>Wins: <output name="score">0</output></label>
      <label>Ties: <output name="score">0</output></label>
      <label>Lost: <output name="score">0</output></label>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Quit">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
  </form>
</dialog>
```

Comment: I am missing the rock emoji in Windows 10. I do have this one  though

Comment: Ha! I used the Moyai emoji  as the rock also. I found the [rock emoji:  HTML: `&#129704;` CSS: `\01faa8` JS: `"\uD83E\uDEA8"`](https://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/rock) later on, it was released 3 years ago. That's odd that you can't use the rock emoji, I am running Windows 10 as well and never had any problems. 

Comment: https://emojipedia.org/microsoft/windows-10/rock - I guess I could install a font that supports it https://winaero.com/get-build-22478-new-emoji-in-windows-10-and-windows-11/