# how can i make my string comparison work?

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, comparison, arr

I know this is a super noob question.

I'm expecting to give a random string to player 2 and compare it to the player... I can see player2 being reassigned , however the if statement doesn't seem to work.

```js
let player = 'paper';
let player2 = '';
let myarr = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
player2 = myarr[index];
console.log(player2);

function compare() {
  if (player === player2)
    console.log("draw");
}
compare(); // you missed this (added by editor)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if statement doesn't seem to work"? In your example code, you aren't calling the ```compare``` function. Also accessing variables of a higher scope isn't a good style. Better for readability would be, when you pass both player values as an argument

Comment: facepalm...Appreciate-it!

Comment: For a great discussion of the "roshambo" game see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77523558/why-does-my-function-only-work-as-function-and-not-functionparam1-param2-et)